# Generating a list in Specman with at least one of each enum

Tags: constants, verification, specman, e, cadence

If I have:

```
<'
type MyEnum : [A1, B2, C3, D4, E5];

extend sys {
     ListA : list of MyEnum;
     keep ListA.size() == 10; // Just for the example,
                              // point being that it is larger than the number of Enums in the type
};
'>
```

How do I add keeps to have `ListA` generate with **at least one** of each enum?

I want this to happen in generation so preferably not to do this on-the-fly.
I can add:

```
extend sys {
     keep ListA.has(it == A1);
     keep ListA.has(it == B2);
     ...
};
```

But there must be a better way. This also isn't helpful if I start adding more to the type.

I also want all of them to be random so having a keep on the first 5 elements that they should be all different isn't as helpful either.

Thank you!

Comment: This is my temporary solution but would love if there was something better:
```
type MyEnum : [A1,B2,C3,D4,E5];
    
extend sys {
    ListA : list of MyEnum;
    keep ListA.size() == 10; 

    ListB : list of bool;
    keep ListB.size() == 10;
    keep ListB.count(it) == all_values(MyEnum).size();
    
    ListC : list of uint;
    keep ListC == ListB.all_indices(it).as_a(list of uint);
    
    keep for each in ListC {
        ListA[it] == all_values(MyEnum)[index];
    };
};

Answer (score 4):

i also use an auxiliary list:

```
all_vals : list of MyEnum;
keep all_vals == all_values(MyEnum);
keep for each in all_vals {
    it in ListA;
};
```

Comment: Add to it also:
`keep ListA.size() >= all_vals.size();`

Comment: "keep all_vals in ListA" should be enough.